# How to set the default argument to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to get my script to set an array as a **default value** for a script if the value is not given as an argument to my script and seem to be having some issues getting Powershell to understand that it's an array.

I've set params as so:

```
param (
    [string]$games = @('Subnautica', 'Gearcity')
)
```

The problem seems to be that `$games` now gets the value of a string "Subnautica Gearcity". At least that's the output of the variable. The comma seems to disappear and thus so does the array when trying to traverse it using `foreach ( $game in $games ) { random jabber }`.

Comment: Both answers here, which are virtually identical and were posted within minutes of each other, offer a valid solution.
In case you're curious (completely optional): Posting virtually identical answers is the subject of [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351296/45375), and that discussion _may_ have had an effect on the answers' scores beyond their intrinsic merit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason this happens is that you have specified that your Parameter `$games` is a string, what you want is an array of strings: `string[]` so your code becomes:

```
param (
    [string[]]$games = @('Subnautica', 'Gearcity')
)
```

Answer (score 7):

This bit: `[string]$games` forces your variable to be a string. To make it an array of strings you need to add`[]` to variable type declaration.

```
[string[]]$games = @('Subnautica', 'Gearcity')
```